# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found - Report Server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to install the opensource version of reportserver (http://reportserver.datenwerke.net/en/)

I have configured the persistence.xml file and changed the details in the lines below:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reportserver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
```

I am now able to successfully access reportserver and log in etc. However, when adding a datasource for an external DB I test the connection and receive the following error.

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found`

I believe that persistence.xml is correct as I am able to change say the username and password of reportserver which is stored on the local database.

Here is a chunk of the stack trace:

```
net.datenwerke.rs.core.service.reportmanager.exceptions.DatabaseConnectionException: Could not open connection to: example.com with user: root. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver<br>   at 
net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.datasources.table.transformers.DatabaseDatasourceTableTransformer.transform(DatabaseDatasourceTableTransformer.java:62)<br>  at 
net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.datasources.table.transformers.DatabaseDatasourceTableTransformer.transform(DatabaseDatasourceTableTransformer.java:1)<br>   at 
net.datenwerke.rs.core.service.datasourcemanager.datasourcetransformers.DatasourceDefinitionTransformerManager.transform(DatasourceDefinitionTransformerManager.java:49)<br>    at 
net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.reportengines.table.SimpleDataSupplier.getData(SimpleDataSupplier.java:118)<br>  at 
net.datenwerke.rs.base.service.reportengines.table.SimpleDataSupplier.getData(SimpleDataSupplier.java:113)<br>  at
```

I have installed both the JDK and tomcat for the project as requested and I have downloaded the Mysql Connector JDBC driver (`mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`). I have placed this into /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/webapps/reportserver/WEB-INF/lib as the instructions state this needs to be installed but does not specify where (http://blog.datenwerke.net/2013/05/installation-and-basic-configuration.html). Am I correct placing this here or should it be placed in the Tomcat lib folder. Also do the names need to be changed etc?

I have literally no experience with Java and I have searched and searched but I need some help to move forward. Can anyone suggest how I might go about fixing this.

For your info:

The external database is a Mysql Database and I can access this from navicat and php scripts etc.

The server I am using is Centos 6.5 64bit.

Many thanks.

**Update**
Here is the full chunk

```
<!-- Connection properties -->
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="net.datenwerke.rs.utils.hibernate.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reportserver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is quite simple and yet quite deceptive. When adding an external datasource you are asked for the Database type ie Mysql, the username, the password and importantly here the URL.
It may seem logical to add the url as you would anything else ie example.com.
The correct format of the URL however should be as shown in the persistence.xml file like so:

jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/databasename

Once you have formatted the url like above then you will find that the connection will establish successfully.

This is a bit of inexperience on my side, but hopefully this will help someone else using reportserver.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing following:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

Comment: Please see the update in my question, it seems this is present, but I did not include in first post.

Comment: and is your mysql on your computer running on port 3306?

Comment: The local db is running on 3306 and I believe this connects fine as the password changes in the DB when I change form the gui. I am also adding another datasource in the gui so I can report form that database. It is this external database where the connection fails. This database is also on 3306 and is accesible from everything else.